# Get twitter entity value from json with PHP

Tags: php, json, twitter

I am looping through each tweet in json feed from twitter. The first part of the code works perfectly...

```
$screen_name = "BandQ";
$count = 10;


$urlone = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=false&screen_name=BandQ&count=".$count."&page=1"),true);
$urltwo = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=false&screen_name=BandQ&count=".$count."&page=2"),true);

$data = array_merge_recursive( $urlone, $urltwo);


// Output tweets
//$json = file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=false&screen_name=".$screen_name."&count=".$count."", true);
//$decode = json_decode($json, true);

$count = count($data); //counting the number of status

$arr = array();
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $text = $data[$i]["text"]." ";
     $retweets = $data[$i]["text"]."<br>Retweet Count: ".$data[$i]["retweet_count"]. "<br>Favourited Count: ".$data[$i]["favorite_count"]."<br>".$data[$i]["entities"]["user_mentions"][0]["screen_name"]."<br>";
    // $arr[] = $text;
    $arr[] = $retweets;
}

// Convert array to string
$arr = implode(" ",$arr);
print_r($arr);
```

but when I try to get entities->user_mentions->screen_name the PHP throws errors...

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\tweets.php on line 29

Notice: Use of undefined constant user_mentions - assumed 'user_mentions' in C:\xampp\htdocs\tweets.php on line 29

Notice: Use of undefined constant screen_name - assumed 'screen_name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\tweets.php on line 29
```

How do I get that screen_name value?

Many thanks

Comment: show us the code you're using that isn't working

Comment: The line above is not the one throwing this error, please show us line 29 exactly as you wrote it

Comment: Line 29 is the line starting $retweets. I am just not traversing the json properly. Tried multiple times to no avail.

Comment: Getting there but now getting Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\tweets.php on line 30